# Is Linux vulnerable to Java drive-by exploits?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virus, malware

**Is Linux vulnerable to Java drive-by exploits?**

Another computer I run on windows 7 just notified me that it was infected through Java, and I'm wondering if my Linux box (ubuntu 10) with Java installed is vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on which operating system is the target of the virus. Linux is less likely to be the target, but some viruses do target Linux as well, and some are even multi-platform.

Your browser should not be configured to automatically execute and trust Java applets. Although Chrome is the youngest browser, some protections are already available.

Plug-ins that you do not use should be disabled:
[Disable Flash, Acrobat, Silverlight & Java Chrome plugins](http://www.tothepc.com/archives/disable-flash-acrobat-silverlight-java-chrome-plugins/).

Dangerous features like JavaScript and third-party plugins like Java and Flash that you do use, should only be enabled for sites that you trust:
[NotScripts: NoScript Extension for Opera and Chrome](http://techie-buzz.com/opera/noscript-extension-opera-chrome.html)
[How to Block Ads in Google Chrome (Privoxy)](http://lifehacker.com/5046529/how-to-block-ads-in-google-chrome)

I suggest installing at least the NotScripts extension as an immediate protection.

Comment: How could I configure it otherwise? I'm not sure if it is, no settings were ever changed. Latest version of Chrome both on Win7 and Linux

Comment: Here is some info about protection.

Answer (score 0):

This guy has been infected with malware through a Java and Flash exploit. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94QsgdXnsmU

So, yes, it is possible, but very rare. You can always do a ClamAV/ClamTk scan wich can be downloaded from ubuntu software center or [here](http://www.clamav.net/index.html)

But i think Click-to-play is secure enough